# Related to sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a doubt in this particular question

Q.
If $$(20)^{19}+2(21)(20)^{18}+3(21)^2(20)^{17}+\cdots+20(21)^{19}=k(20)^{19}$$ then find the value of $k$

In this I have tried to solve it by first taking out the general term and then calculating the sum but eventually I am not getting the correct answer which is $400$.

Can you tell me where I am going wrong in solving this question and is my method of solving this question correct?? Can we solve such type of questions by taking general term??

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you mean with ‘taking out the general term’?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note the terms of the sum of a [Arithmetico–geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence), with this Wikipedia article giving you a formula you can fairly easily use to directly calculate its sum.

Comment: Going by @JohnOmielan comment, I have tried this:$$\begin{align}a=1, b=20^{19}, d=1, r=\frac{21}{20} \implies (a+nd)=21, br^n=20^{19}\cdot\left(\frac{21}{20}\right)^{20}=20\cdot21^{20},& dbr=1\cdot 20^{19}\cdot\frac{21}{20}=21\cdot20^{18} \end{align}$$

We have the  following: $$\begin{align}\frac{20^{19}-(21)(20\cdot21^{20})}{1-\frac{21}{20}}+\frac{21\cdot20^{18}\cdot(1-(\frac{21}{20})^{20})}{(1-\frac{21}{20})^2} =& 20\cdot((21)(20\cdot21^{20})-20^{19})+20^{20}\cdot 21\cdot(1-(\frac{21}{20})^{20}) \end{align}$$ $$=21^{21}\cdot20^2-20^{20}+21\cdot(20^{20}-21^{20})$$

Comment: Can you give the answer without applying general formula.

Comment: @s1mple Thanks for showing your work. You made a mistake. In your $br^n = 20^{19}\cdot \left(\frac{21}{20}\right)^{20} = 20\cdot 21^{20}$, the value is actually $\frac{21^{20}}{20}$ instead. Using this corrected value, the first term in your final line is different, so your final line should be $21^{21} - 20^{20} + 21\cdot(20^{20} - 21^{20})$. Thus, when you expand the final term, the $21^{21}$ terms cancel, so you get $21^{21} - 20^{20} + 21\cdot 20^{20} - 21^{21} = 20\cdot 20^{20} = 400\cdot 20^{19}$. This matches what the OP says is the correct answer, & is also what's in Mostafa's answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, $k$ must be $$k=1+2\left({21\over 20}\right)+3\left({21\over 20}\right)^2+\cdots +20\left({21\over 20}\right)^{19}$$which can be written as $$k=\sum_{i=1}^{20} i\left({21\over 20}\right)^{i-1}$$By defining $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{20} ix^{i-1}={d\over dx}\sum_{i=1}^{20} x^{i}$$it is clear that 
$$
k{={d\over dx}\sum_{i=1}^{20} x^{i}\Bigg|_{x={21\over 20}}
\\={d\over dx}\left[{x^{21}-1\over x-1}-1\right]_{x={21\over 20}}
\\=\left[{21x^{20}(x-1)-(x^{21}-1)\over (x-1)^2}\right]_{x={21\over 20}}
\\={\left({21\over 20}\right)^{21}-\left[({21\over 20}\right)^{21}-1]\over \left({1\over 20}\right)^2}
\\=400
}
$$